# how to consume JS promises when it is chained?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

In the below code why am I getting a in the last line as undefined? How do I write to get response in variable a

````
function getData(){
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
url2='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'
fetch(url).then((res) =>{
  res.json().then((dataAsJson) => {
    return(dataAsJson[0].id);
  })
  .then((id)=>{
     fetch(url2+"/"+id).then((res)=> {
     return res.json().then((data) => {
      return(data);
    })
    })
})

})
}


var a = getData();
console.log(a)```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing two return statements to actually pass the values from one promise to the next. So to make your code work, you have to include them:

```js
async function getData(){
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  url2='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'
  const data = await fetch(url).then((res) =>{
    return res.json().then((dataAsJson) => {
      return(dataAsJson[0].id);
    })
  .then((id)=>{
     return fetch(url2+"/"+id).then((res)=> {
        return res.json().then((data) => {
          return(data);
        })
      })
    })
  })
}
```

One more tip here: When returning from a promise, it doesn't matter if it is another promise or a simple value - the next `then` call will always get the unwrapped value. So you actually don't have to nest all those promise calls. It would be way more readble if you put it like this:

```js
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
url2='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'
const data = await fetch(url)
  .then((res) =>{ return res.json()})
  .then((dataAsJson) => { return(dataAsJson[0].id); })
  .then((id)=>{ return fetch(url2+"/"+id); })
  .then((res)=> { return res.json(); })
```

And also: Since you are just returning one value in each callback, you can make use of the JavaScript-Arrow-Function functionality that automatically returns if there is only one expression and short it even more to this:

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
url2 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/';
const data = await fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(dataAsJson => dataAsJson[0].id)
  .then(id => fetch(`${url2}/${id}`))
  .then(res => res.json());
```

That is better readable and errors are easier to spot. :)

**Update: I totally overlooked that in your code, your are trying to read synchronsouly from the asynchronous `getData()` function. @the spectre cleared that up in his answer - so this should be the accepted one. However, to not let a wrong code stand, I edited the correct behaviour into my answer.**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to streamline that function with the use of `await`.
It removes the need for nested callbacks. This code isn't tested but should in theory work.

```
async function getData() {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  const url2 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/";

  const firstFetch = await fetch(url)
  const firstResult = await firstFetch.json();

  const id = firstResult[0].id;

  const secondFetch = await fetch(url2 + "/" + id)
  return await secondFetch.json();
}
```

https://javascript.info/async-await

You could alternatively create a new promise to resolve in your second fetch. But this approach is messier

Comment: [https://repl.it/repls/UntruePitifulSystemsanalysis]  I tried to use this...but its returning me pending promise..How do I counsume this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not returning anything from `getData()` you're getting undefined.

Promises and their chained methods, `then()` and `catch` will return an instance of Promise themselves, not the data you're returning from the callback in `then()`.

To get the behavior you're expecting, one way is to use `async` and `await`. Piggybacking off of David, you'd do:

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
const url2 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/';
const data = await fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(dataAsJson => dataAsJson[0].id)
  .then(id => fetch(`${url2}/${id}`))
  .then(res => res.json());
  
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Right, I oversaw that one. Thanks for clearing it - this should be the accepted answer!